# Java application whith a loop, a string input and a .equals(" ") method

Tags: java, string, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Homework task:
Write a Java program which asks the user to input the text “Ask question”. Program has to work in a loop and can’t accept an empty string nor a space. When the sample question is being entered the message “thank you” is displayed.

It does not work properly.
Please help

```
    String s;
    String a = "What is your name?";


    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Ask a question");

    s = input.nextLine();

    while(!s.equals(a))

    {
        System.out.println("Ask a question ! ! !");
    }

    System.out.println("Thank You");
```

I've been trying to make the code work but it still cannot work properly. I want it to work like that:
If a person enters "What is your name?" the program should output "Thank you" (and that works now.)
If a person enters nothing or a space the program should print "Ask a question ! ! !" and make it possible for the person to enter the input again (it does not work like that now; it displays "ask question ! ! !" infinitely.

Comment: You never change `s` or `a` inside the loop, so how did you expect the loop to ever end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking the same input string over and over again, because, you're not updating it in `while` loop. This should do it:

```
while(!s.equals(a)){
    System.out.println("Ask a question ! ! !");
    s = input.nextLine();
}
```